# asp.net mvc 4 default route not specified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking at setting up a custom route in my mvc 4 application without default parameter defaults
(http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

I modified it slightly:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Blog",                                           // Route name
            "Archive/{entryDate}"                            // URL with parameters
);
```

the problem is I am getting an error when hitting :

```
http://localhost:80/Archive/12-25-2009

The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a `Controller` that this route will hit.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Blog",                                           // Route name
    "Archive/{entryDate}",                        // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Archive", action = "Entry" }
);
```

Without that, the route doesn't know what `Controller` your request should be "routed" to. That is because your default route appears to be missing.. which will fall back to your home controller generally.